# Combination of percentiles from different data sets: how can this be accomplished?

Tags: database, matlab, language-agnostic

I need to compute the Nth percentiles of a series of related, but segmented data sets.

The combined data sets are too large to compute all at once due to memory limitations, but the framework to perform piece-wise calculations is already in place. So how might I perform calculations on each data set and then combine those calculations to find the percentile that I need?

Other information about the data:

- The data often has outliers.
- The individual data sets tend to be roughly the same size, but not always
- The individual data sets are not expected to share the same distribution

Could I compute the combined median, means, and standard deviations and then estimate any percentile from there?

Comment: The answer that you pointed is not answering the question

Answer (score 0):

The median, mean and standard deviation alone are unlikely to be enough, especially if you have outliers.

If exact percentiles are required, this is a parallel computation problem. Some work has been done in this direction, such as in the [parallel mode of the C++ STL library](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/parallel_mode.html).

If only approximate percentiles are required then Cross Validated has a question -- [Estimation of quantile given quantiles of subset](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171784/estimation-of-quantile-given-quantiles-of-subset) -- that suggests a subsampling approach. You would take some (but not all) datapoints from each dataset, make a new combined dataset that is small enough to fit on a single machine and compute the percentiles of that.

Another approximate approach, efficient if percentiles of each segment are already available, would be to approximate the [cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) of each segment as a step function from the percentiles. Then the overall distribution would be a [finite mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Finite_and_countable_mixtures) of the segment distributions and the cumulative distribution function a weighted sum of the segment cumulative distribution functions. The quantile function (i.e., the percentiles) could be computed by numerically inverting the cumulative distribution function.